# Story I read in an EC Vault of Horror/Tales From The Crypt style comic book

Tags: story-identification, comics, horror, mutant, virus

I remember reading an issue of a *Vault of Horror*/*Tales From The Crypt* type comic in the late 70s/the early 80s, and one story stuck with me and I am trying to track it down.

The story centers around a honeymooning couple who are on an ocean cruise liner. Everything is going fine until the crew of the ship pick up a survivor in a lifeboat. This survivor is infected with some kind of virus/disease which is spread by contact with another person and compels the infected individual to pass it on to any uninfected in proximity (similar to the Crossed virus, or the Rage virus). It also mutates the infected to a (slightly) larger size and makes them ugly (oversized forehead, deep set eyes, like the Hulk, or Ben Grimm).

The newlyweds manage to barricade themselves in their cabin until they are the only ones uninfected, but as the infected try to break in, they decide to climb out of the window and take their chances in the sea. The husband manages to climb outside, but as his wife is climbing through the window the infected break in and someone grabs her ankle, passing the virus to her, and the husband is forced to abandon her.

Does this ring a bell with anyone?

Comment: I removed the thanks as, according to SE, that is just noise. I also made a few minor changes in the layout but overall this is a nicely written post!

Comment: Do you by any chance mean the story where 2 people are stranded on a boat, and the husband has to go and row to an island where he contracts the disease?

Comment: No, it's definitely a ship and the husband is the only one to escape. The wife may have been in a wedding dress the whole time. The ship picks up the infected man in a small boat and the "condition" spreads by touch.

Comment: Do you recall the name of the anthology?

Comment: For instance, could it actually be the Vault of Horror or the Tales from the Crypt comics?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't as I was just a kid, it could be either or neither, which really isn't helpful!

Comment: Do you know whether or not either the Tales from the Crypt live-action show or animated series adapted this storyline?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry, never seen either